# PHP simplexml reading child tag attribute

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have a xml like below,

```
<y>
 <n>
   <n id='test1'></n>
   <n id='test2'></n>
 </n>
</y>
```

and want to read each "id"  of  child "n" tag .

I use this php code;

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("my.xml");
echo $xml->n[0]->n;
```

but getting error,

> Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be : `$xml->n->n[0]` which is an array. If you `print_r($xml)` you might see like this:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [n] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [n] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => test1
                            )

                    )

                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => test2
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Comment: ...and don't forget that `id` is a node attribute and not the node value so you need to fetch it like this: `echo $xml->n->n[0]['id']`.